# How to fit html to certain height? (without wrappers)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Important:** I need to do this without any divs or other wrappers.

I want to fit the scrollable text into the fixed-size frame...

https://jsfiddle.net/x128/yf4btorn/

CSS:

```
html {
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/IPhone_5s_golden.svg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: 300px 630px;
  background-position: center;
}
body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -120px;
}
```

Add any long text:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement("DIV");
  div.innerText = "This text should fit into the phone \"screen\"";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
  document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

Why don't HTML height/margin/padding affect the displayed height?

[image: Demo]

P.S. I really need this scroll without divs/tables/etc. I want my `body` to be totally controlled with a 3rd party code (p5.js), I can only add CSS or JS files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the css like this .Hide the overflow of html  and Fixed the correct height and width of body with respect to black screen.

**[`See the demo fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/yf4btorn/3/)**

```
html {
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/IPhone_5s_golden.svg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: 300px 630px;
  background-position: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  width: 260px;
  height:450px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -130px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```